# Find and replace multiple values

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find all cells with specific values, color the cells (and 3 cells next to it in a row) blue.

I recorded Find&Select and it works, but I cannot figure out how to make cells next to found one be colored as well.

I tried several range things - because data we look for or the color changes often, it would be painful to change all recorded codes one by one - but any changes I did made the macro fail completely.

Below works but will be painful to adjust

```vb
Sub findNcolor() ' ' Macro1 Macro '

    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Cells.Replace What:="AAA", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True

    Cells.Replace What:="CCC", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart,
SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True

    Cells.Replace What:="DDD", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart,
SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True

End Sub
```

I would like cells marked in yellow be colored blue as well, as soon as macro finds cell "AAA" (the same for other searches, ex 'BBB', 'DDD' etc.).
[image]

Comment: `.resize(1,4).`

Comment: Is cell `C5` a merged cell? Do you want to highlight the cells `C6:J7` (I can see that they are merged), too?

Comment: Yes it is. I want to fill with color cells D:J for whatever value is being searched (AAA, BBB, etc.).
It is especially difficult for me to figure it out, since some of the files have just one row (like in AAA or HHH), but they can have up to 6 rows (like CCC or DDD have 4 in this instance).

Comment: Sorry, I'm just curious.... are (X) the rows also merged if there are more than 1 row of data or (Y) just the columns are merged ? For example, the value "CCC", if it's (X) then "CCC" is in the range B5:C7 - if it's (Y) then "CCC" is in the range B5:C5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?
The code assumed that "AAA", "BBB", etc is in a merged column B and C. Each row in Column D is just a row in column D, each row from columns E to G is merged and each row from columns H to J is also merged.

```
Sub test()
Set rg = Range("B3", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each cell In rg
        cell.Resize(1, 6).Interior.Color = 15773696
    Next
End Sub
```

The code only take the cell which has value in column B (AAA, BBB, CCC etc), and then put the color of row resized range from column A to J.

[image]